# Как преобразовать кодировку csv?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь делать импорт из csv-файла. Если кодировка у csv отличается от utf-8, к примеру равна windows-1251, то выводятся кракозябры

```
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $item = trim($data[$c]);
            echo $item . ' ' . mb_detect_encoding($item);
            //здесь если в $item латиница, то выводится `ASCII`,
            //а если кириллица, то выводится `UTF-8` но вместо символов кракозябры(квадратик с вопросом)
```

если в начале файла добавить эту строчку `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251');`
то кракозябр нет из csv-файла в переменной `$item`, но появляются кракозябры в админке, там где был русский текст.
Как это можно настроить, чтобы и в админке и в csv была кириллица?

**P.S.**

```
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
            $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($item));
            $item = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "utf-8", $item);
```

использовал по очереди эти варианты конвертации, кракозябры остались

Comment: [Конверсия кодировки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) в UTF-8

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, я это забыл добавить в вопрос, но я проверял конверсию разными способами, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Может всё-таки посмотреть на результаты этих функций и их ответы в виде предупреждений, так как просто «не работает» не прокатит? У вас в коде написано про ASCII кодировку, а не Windows-1251.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, ascii показывает, когда в $item латиница, а когда в $item кириллица, то показывает utf-8, но выводит кракозябры